# Retrieve value from dynamically created control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dropdown lists, one for days and one for nights. I also have two buttons, one button creates dynamic textboxes where the customer can enter what they want to do in day time and in place where they want to spend night.

e.g., if one customer selects 4 days and 4 nights, a textbox will be created on press of the first button.

When the user clicks the second button, I want to store all those values in database, but I noticed that on postback the fields are lost and I have no data to store.

How do I get the values from the controls created at runtime upon postback?

Comment: How are you creating the Dynamic Textboxes? Javascript, Codebehind

Comment: In order for us to help you, you have to post your code.

Comment: please paste your Page_load event....

Comment: You'll need to look through you forms control collection. Can you post some snippets of the code?

Comment: There are 2 button, if user client on 1 a textbox is created and on button 2 textbox retrieve value

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (Session["testTextBox"] != null)
    {
        Request.Form[Session["testTextBox"].ToString()].ToString()
    }
 }

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    TextBox t = new TextBox { ID = "testTextBox" };
    this.Form.Controls.Add(t);
    Session["testTextBox"] = t.UniqueID;
 }
```

If you are adding the textbox via a client side call you don't need to store the UniqueID. Button1_Click is the postback method for your button for example.

Answer (score 0):

Even though adding controls in code behind is "fine", it can lead to trouble later. It also isn't very good when editing your view, and you have to change a bunch of code in code-behind. A solution is to use a data bound control, for instance a Repeater control. That way, you can design your view in your *aspx* file, and leave the coding to the cs-file. It also takes care of holding information when using postbacks, since it's already setup to use the viewstate of the controls, meaning you don't have to do it.

So, using a repeater, your aspx can look something like this.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RepeaterPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASPTest.RepeaterPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div>
        <asp:Button Text="Add textbox" ID="Button1" OnClick="OnAddItem" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button Text="Read values" ID="Button2" OnClick="OnReadValues" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="values" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="listofvalues" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="ID" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="ValueBox" Text='<%# Server.HtmlEncode((string)Eval("Value")) %>' runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

Notice that I'm using a master page, so the Content control only links to some ContentPlaceHolder in the master page. In this aspx page, you'll see that the itemtemplate in the repeater control sets up all the design needed to show the values. We'll see how this pans out in the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ASPTest
{
    public partial class RepeaterPage : Page
    {
        private List<Item> cache;
        public List<Item> ItemValues
        {
            get
            {
                if (cache != null)
                {
                    return cache;
                }
                // load values from database for instance
                cache = Session["values"] as List<Item>;
                if (cache != null)
                {
                    return cache;
                }
                Session["values"] = cache = new List<Item>();
                return cache;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            listofvalues.DataBinding += bindValues;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void OnAddItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ItemValues.Add(new Item("some value"));
            DataBind();
        }

        protected void OnReadValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem repeateritem in listofvalues.Items)
            {
                TextBox box = (TextBox)repeateritem.FindControl("ValueBox");
                HiddenField idfield = (HiddenField)repeateritem.FindControl("ID");
                Item item = findItem(idfield.Value);
                item.Value = box.Text;
            }
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (Item item in ItemValues)
            {
                builder.Append(item.Value).Append(";");
            }
            values.Text = builder.ToString();
        }

        private Item findItem(string idvalue)
        {
            Guid guid = new Guid(idvalue);
            foreach (Item item in ItemValues)
            {
                if (item.ID == guid)
                {
                    return item;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void bindValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listofvalues.DataSource = ItemValues;
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        private readonly Guid id;
        private string value;

        public Item(string value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public Guid ID
        {
            get { return id; }
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get { return value; }
            set { this.value = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry about the long code example, but I wanted it to be thorough. You'll see that I introduced a list of Items, in the ItemValues property. You can load the values from wherever you want. I used the Session collection, but you can load from database or some other place if you want.

Also, notice how the only thing we know about the view is the control type and control ID. There's no code describing how controls should be added or styled, we leave that to the aspx page. This creates an easy separation of concerns between the two.

Instead, when we want to add a *TextBox*, we instead add a new instance of the data item, an instance of the `Item` class. In the OnReadValues method we can update the data items values bound to the repeater, and then use either the values from the controls or the values from the items in our data list.

I hope this illustrates how one can use ASP.NET to create dynamic pages, without creating the controls in code behind, because it's not really needed if you do it like this.